# Windows 11 WSL Ubuntu 22.04: /mnt/c/Strawberry/perl/bin/cpanm: perl: bad interpreter:

Tags: windows, perl, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install `Perl::LanguageServer` on Ubuntu 22.04 under WSL on Windows 11:

From the Ubuntu 22.04 terminal window:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install cpanminus
$ cpanm Perl::LanguageServer
-bash: /mnt/c/Strawberry/perl/bin/cpanm: perl: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I would like to install the module using `/usr/bin/cpanm` but apparently it is finding the  Strawberry perl cpanm even though `/usr/bin` comes before `/mnt/c/Strawberry/perl/bin` in `PATH`:

```
$  echo $PATH | perl -nE 'say for split ":"'
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/usr/lib/wsl/lib
/mnt/c/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI
[...]
/mnt/c/Strawberry/perl/bin
[...]
 
$ /usr/bin/cpanm --version
cpanm (App::cpanminus) version 1.7045 (/usr/bin/cpanm)
$ /mnt/c/Strawberry/perl/bin/cpanm --version
-bash: /mnt/c/Strawberry/perl/bin/cpanm: perl: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Any idea why it does not search PATH in the usual order?

Comment: Does running `hash cpanm` fix it?

Comment: @Shawn Yes it does!

Comment: Probably tried running cpanm in the same bash shell before installing it, and bash cached the path to the Windows version.

Comment: *"Probably tried running cpanm in the same bash shell before installing it"* Yes I think you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Shawn for the solution.

According to the Bash reference manual, [Section 3.7.2 Command Search and Execution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Search-and-Execution)

> Bash searches each element of $PATH for a directory containing an executable file by that name. Bash uses a hash table to remember the full pathnames of executable files to avoid multiple PATH searches (see the description of hash in Bourne Shell Builtins). A full search of the directories in $PATH is performed only if the command is not found in the hash table.

Further, in [Chapter 4.1 Bourne Shell Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins):

> **hash**
>
> `hash [-r] [-p filename] [-dt] [name]`
> Each time hash is invoked, it remembers the full pathnames of the commands specified as name arguments, so they need not be searched for on subsequent invocations. The commands are found by searching through the directories listed in $PATH. Any previously-remembered pathname is discarded.

So if you in a new shell use a command and then move it to another place, bash will not recognize that unless you explicitly call hash on that command.

In my case, I first tried to run `cpanm Perl::LanguageServer` and bash found the Strawberry Perl version of that command and remembered the location of that. But that version of `cpanm` is not useable in the WSL Ubuntu terminal, so I installed a new `cpanm` using `sudo apt-get install cpanminus` into the Ubuntu virtual machine. When I retried `cpanm Perl::LanguageServer` after that, bash did not consult `PATH` to find the newly installed `cpanm` but rather used its internal hashtable lookup to find the location of the command, which was still the Strawberry perl version of cpanm. The solution was to run

```
hash cpanm
```

to force a rehash of the command.